# How to use DatePickerComponent in a sharedModule

Tags: angular

I have a DatePickerComponent works fine in AppModule.
I created a SharedModule to use the datePicker in different modules, i included the DatePickerComponent in it.
That's how my SharedModule looks like

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpF3s.png)

Then i imported the ShareModule in AppModule.

`@NgModule({
imports: [
SahredModuleModule, ...]
export class AppModule { }`

[I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMsH3.png)

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `NgbModule` as well to the exports array of your `SharedModule`. That's what will be required for the DatePicker to load.

Something like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { NgbdDatepickerBasic } from '../datepicker-basic';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [NgbdDatepickerBasic],
  exports: [
    NgbdDatepickerBasic, 
    NgbModule /*THIS RIGHT HERE*/
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yne78v?file=app/shared/shared.module.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Thank you, that works fine in AppModule, but not with lazy Modules!

Comment: Sorry! I didn't assume that you were intending to use it in a Lazy Loaded module as you didn't mention anything about it in your question. But I don't think it should matter as long as you're importing the SharedModule in that Lazy Loaded Module. To keep this thread more focused, would you mind asking a separate question about the exact scenario and add a reproducible sample stackblitz to work with?